# BluetoothGatt connection timeout status 0x22/ GATT_CONN_LMP_TIMEOUT

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

i am currently working on 2 app which one emulates as a  BLE Peripheral which is advertising using the bluetoothadvertiser and the other is a Client.
The Peripheral*BluetoothGattServerCallback* - Honor8 *Nougat 7.0*
The Client*BluetoothGattCallback* - Nexus 7 2013 *Marshmallow 6.0*

I have managed to get them connected successfully using the:

`bluetoothgatt = BTdevice.connectGatt(activity,false,callback);`

The Nexus 7 connects to the Honor 8 fine,however after about 30 seconds or so the connection times out and i get error: `06-06 11:12:06.305 15683-15694/project.androidads I/BLE: ReportedConnectionChanged:GATT CONN LMP TIMEOUT Connection error:UNKNOWN (0)`

Client Log:

`06-06 11:11:25.992 15683-15683/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5, auto: false
06-06 11:11:25.993 15683-15683/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
06-06 11:11:25.993 15683-15683/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=dab3140d-6d26-48ef-b956-02c38aa3dfe8
06-06 11:11:25.995 15683-15694/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
06-06 11:11:26.488 15683-15710/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5
06-06 11:11:26.490 15683-15710/project.androidads I/BLE: ReportedConnectionChanged:SUCCESS Connection error:GATT READ NOT PERMIT
06-06 11:11:26.490 15683-15710/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5
06-06 11:11:26.491 15683-15710/project.androidads I/Tag: CONNECTED
06-06 11:11:26.491 15683-15710/project.androidads D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-06 11:11:26.499 15683-15710/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5 Status=0
06-06 11:11:26.506 15683-15710/project.androidads I/BLE: Service:ccaa55ee-7777-aa14-8000-2742f1ba77cc
06-06 11:11:27.661 15683-15710/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: ccaa55ee-7777-aa14-aae1-112855353cc1 enable: true
06-06 11:11:27.661 15683-15710/project.androidads I/BLE: onCharacteristicRead UUID:ccaa55ee-7777-aa14-aae1-112855353cc1
06-06 11:11:27.662 15683-15710/project.androidads I/BLE: onCharacteristicRead:0
06-06 11:12:06.305 15683-15694/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=34 clientIf=6 device=5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5
06-06 11:12:06.305 15683-15694/project.androidads I/BLE: ReportedConnectionChanged:GATT CONN LMP TIMEOUT Connection error:UNKNOWN (0)
06-06 11:12:06.305 15683-15694/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 5A:89:20:7A:C2:C5
06-06 11:12:06.306 15683-15694/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: close()
06-06 11:12:06.306 15683-15694/project.androidads D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
06-06 11:12:06.306 15683-15694/project.androidads I/TAG: FAILED:34and:0`

Peripheral Log:

`06-06 11:11:24.918 22412-22424/project.androidads I/BLE: ReportedConnectionChanged:SUCCESS Connection error:GATT READ NOT PERMIT
06-06 11:11:24.918 22412-22424/project.androidads I/BLE: connected
06-06 11:11:26.179 22412-22425/project.androidads I/BLE: CharacteristicReadRequest Elasped:ccaa55ee-7777-aa14-aae1-112855353cc1
06-06 11:12:24.881 22412-22425/project.androidads I/BLE: ReportedConnectionChanged:SUCCESS Connection error:UNKNOWN (0)
06-06 11:12:24.881 22412-22425/project.androidads I/BLE: disconnected`

Been working on this for couple days and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong,is it the code or there is hardware limitations. Much help would be appreciated.

Comment: getting the same error on Nokia 2 and lenevo K8 phone with Nougat

Comment: how to overcome this problm?